# A simple 'if' statement

Tags: bash, if-statement

My problem can be simplified down to making the following script work (which takes one command line argument):

```
#!/bin/bash
if ["$1" == "0"]; then
    echo "good"
else
    echo "bad"
fi
```

This should print **good** when I run **script 0**, but I can't get it to. I've tried various combinations of quotes around the numbers, and I've tried =, ==, and -eq. So... bash, how does it work?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `[` is actually a command. Do a `ls /bin/[` or an `ls /usr/bin/[`. You'll see it's actually an executable file.

The `[...]` is from the old Bourne shell days. The `if` command executes the statement, and if the exit code of that statement is a zero, the statement is considered *true* and the if clause is executed. If the exit code is not zero, the else clause is executed (if present).

Try these:

```
$ date
Fri May 18 00:04:03 EDT 2012
echo $?   #Prints the exit code of the date command
0

$ date -Q  #Shouldn't work, I hope...
date: illegal option -- q
usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
    [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
$ echo $?    #Exit code for the date command
1
```

You can see that `date` is a valid command and returns an exit code of 0 (the value of `$?`), but `date -Q` isn't valid, and returns an exit code of 1.

Now let's try them in the `if` statement:

```
if date
then
   echo "I've successfully printed out the date!"
else
   echo "I made a mistake in the command"
fi
```

Now try this:

```
if date -q
then
   echo "I've successfully printed out the date!"
else
   echo "I made a mistake in the command"
fi
```

Originally, the `[...]` was an alias for the `test` command. The following are equivalent:

```
if test -f /bin/ls    #Does a file called /bin/ls exist?
then
   echo "There's a /bin/ls file"
fi
```

and

```
if [ -f /bin/ls ]
then
   echo "There's a /bin/ls file"
fi
```

This is why it's very important to put spaces around the `[` and `]`. Because these are actually commands. In BASH, there's built into the shell, but they are commands. That's also why all the test parameters (things like `-f`, `-z`, and `-eq`) all are prefixed with dashes. They were originally parameters for the `test` command.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the informative answer. I thought it was just part of the bash syntax.

Comment: It is part and isn't part of bash syntax. It's a built-in command, like `read` or `echo`. These also are now built into the shell, but the executables still exist in the `/bin` or `/usr/bin` directories.

Comment: It's now a built-in command in bash, but it's still just a synonym for `test`, not syntax.

Answer (score 16):

Use a space between the bracket and the argument

```
$ cat x
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" == "0" ]; then
    echo "good"
else
    echo "bad"
fi

$ bash x 0
good
```

Answer (score 12):

Use double parentheses for arithmetic comparisons, then you don't need to worry about quotes and spacings, for example:

```
#!/bin/bash 
if (($1 == 0)); then 
    echo "good" 
else 
    echo "bad" 
fi
```

General rule: use `(( ))` for arithmetics and `[[ ]]` for text and patterns.
As others have said, [ is old Bourne shell syntax and there are few reasons for using it any more.