# Why is this bash script fetching http headers

Tags: linux, git, bash

I am not sure if this was the proper place to post this, none-the-less: I am developing a script to negative match git branches, however when this part was run, it tried to get HTTP headers....can someone explain how this is happening?

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
array_not_contains()
{
    local array="$1[@]"
    local seeking=$2
    local in=0
    for element in "${!array}"; do
        echo $element #Commenting out this echo will stop it from fetching headers
        if [[ $element =~ $seeking ]]; then
            in=1
            break
        fi
    done
    return $in
}

exclude=() #array that will exclude the following matches from deletion
exclude+=(HEAD)
exclude+=(master)
exclude+=(develop)
exclude+=(example.*)


if $(array_not_contains exclude $1); then
    echo "win"
else
    echo "fail"
fi
```

Running it like this:
    ./test.sh bob
will return headers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a Bash array contains a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685970/check-if-a-bash-array-contains-a-value)

Comment: Add `set -x` to see what's happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's ending up evaluating [`HEAD`](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/libwww-perl/HEAD.1p.en.html) as a command.

```
bash$ type -all HEAD
HEAD is /usr/bin/HEAD
```

You probably misunderstand what `if $(command)` does.  It runs `command`, then runs *the output of that* as a command, and examines its exit code.

The fix is easy: you mean

```
if array_contains exclude "$1"; then
```

though I would probably refactor the code to reduce its complexity more significantly.

As pointed out [numerous times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646465/bash-simple-if-statement) the `if` statement runs a command and examines its exit code.

```
bash$ flase () { echo "flase."; return 1; }

bash$ ture () { echo "ture."; return 0; }

bash$ if ture; then echo It is true.; else echo It is not.; fi
ture.
It is true.

bash$ if flase; then echo It is not false.; else echo It is false.; fi
flase.
It is false.
```

Comment: Did you test this on macOS by any chance? `HEAD` isn't typically a command, but HFS+ is case-preserving, meaning it doesn't differentiate between `head` and `HEAD` as  a file name, but keeps the case used in the call.

Comment: I linked the `HEAD` man page - it's a libwww-perl command which is still installed many places.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Another reason to dislike HFS+'s default case-handling.

Comment: I am using an array to store regex match rules which will probably end up being fetched from somewhere outside the script, so reducing complexity is a bit hard(this is also a simplified snippet of code, not showing how the function is actually used). The point of having it run the array_not_contains function is to run the function and then evaluate its exit code(the echos are just for debugging purposes). Your fix does not allow the function to run, which means that the if does not fail on a positive match...defeating the whole point of the script

Comment: How does it not allow the function to run? Did you test??  The argument to `if` is a command line which is run by the shell.

Comment: I did indeed test

Comment: Ah sorry, it does run, but it does not evaluate the return/exit of the function, which is what i need. i also tried [ ] but it didn't work.

Comment: Read slowly. The *purpose* of `if` is to run a command and examine its exit code. This is a FAQ. See e.g. the accepted answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646465/bash-simple-if-statement

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160004/discussion-between-al-urbasebelon-tomeh-and-tripleee).